# Is it possible for a webextension/addon to request permission for a specific website at runtime?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I am trying to develop a WebExtension that accesses a user-defined API whose URL I do not know in advance. (More specifically, it manages their [Ghost](https://ghost.org) publications, whose APIs would be hosted on the same domains as the publications themselves). Hence, I need to let users enter their API URL and access that throughout the addon.

The simplest way to do this would be to request the `<all_urls>` host permission (basically like `*://**`). But instead of such sweeping permissions, I was wondering if there's a more finegrained way of requesting permission just for the specific URL I need?

I know that the `optional_permissions` setting lets an addon request additional permissions at runtime *if* those permissions are specified in advance in the manifest. From [this w3cub page](https://docs.w3cub.com/web_extensions/manifest.json/optional_permissions.html):

> | Type | Mandatory | Example |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Array | No | `"optional_permissions": ["*://developer.mozilla.org/*", "webRequest"]` |
>
> Use the optional_permissions key to list permissions that you want to ask for at runtime, after your extension has been installed.

However, this seems to require a hard-coded permission (`*://developer.mozilla.org/*`) that's requested at runtime. What I need is a *user-defined* permission that can be requested in the same manner. Is there any way I can go about implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the list of use-cases for optional permissions [on the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions):

> - The extension may need [host permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#host_permissions), but not know at install time which host permissions it needs. For example, the list of hosts may be a user setting. In this scenario, asking for a more specific range of hosts at runtime, can be an alternative to asking for "<all_urls>" at install time.

The way to do it is to include `<all_urls>` in the `optional_permissions` setting of your `manifest.json` like this:

```
"optional_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequest",
    "geoLocation"
],
```

In this example, we're also requesting the `webRequest` and `geoLocation` permissions; this is to demonstrate the two different kinds of permission you can request.

Then, in your code, instead of requesting `<all_urls>`, just request the URLs that you actually want to access:

```
browser.permissions.request({
    permissions: ["webRequest", "geoLocation"],
    origins: ["https://example.com/*"]
})
```

As you can see, the request is neatly separated into an option for more API permissions and another for the different websites (origins) you want to access.

A more complete example can be found on the docs for [permissions.request docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/request#examples). (You can also find a working sample webextension [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/permissions), but it doesn't include host permissions, only API ones).